# django import_export | data not exported from database

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I am using Django-import_export for exporting data. I have used the code given below that's not working correctly. It exported only dehydrated data instead of given fields.

```
class MemberResource(resources.ModelResource):
    Brand=Field()
    class meta:
        model = model
        fields=('title','Brand')
    def dehydrate_Brand(self, obj):
        return str(obj.Brand.title)

class modelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = MemberResource
    list_display=['title','Model_code','Chipset','chipset_description','Brand','categories']
    search_fields = ['title','Model_code','Chipset',]
    fields=('title','Model_code','Chipset','chipset_description','image','Brand','Cat')
admin.site.register(model,modelAdmin)
```

Comment: rename `meta` to `Meta`.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the `Meta` subclass is `Meta`, not `meta`, so the `ModelResource` should look like:

```
class MemberResource(resources.ModelResource):
    Brand=Field()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('title','Brand')
    
    def dehydrate_Brand(self, obj):
        return str(obj.Brand.title)
```